# How to produce ATOM formatted ODATA service with ASP.NET WebApi 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, atom-feed

How can you produce ATOM formatted output in an ASP.NET WebApi 2.2 ODATA service? Creating the JSON version, or the simple XML format is easy. But no matter how I request the Content-Type, I always get the 1st format in the configuration. (Using PostMan for Chrome, or setting the Request's Content-Type in the producer method.)

If I use WCF Data Service, I get ATOM formatted result. But as far as I understand, the ODATA v4 is only implemented in WebApi, not in WCF. So, it seems a bit odd, that I can't format it any way I like...

My configuration code is the basic:

```
   config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: null,
        model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

Thanks,

AntiTalent

**UPDATE**:
Using the [typical solution found on the net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210661/get-the-odata-catalog-for-web-api-odata-v4-in-xml/25269213#25269213) (link from 1st comment, @mdisibrio), I get this (WebApi 2.2):

```
<ODataServiceDocument 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.OData.Core">
  <EntitySets>
    <ODataEntitySetInfo>
      <Name>Projects</Name>
      <Title i:nil="true"/>
      <Url>Projects</Url>
    </ODataEntitySetInfo>
  </EntitySets>
  <FunctionImports/>
  <Singletons/>
</ODataServiceDocument>
```

But what I would like to get is (WCF Data Service):

```
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"
 xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
 xml:base="http://MYSERVER/Service.svc/">
  <workspace>
    <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
    <collection href="ProjectList">
    <atom:title>ProjectList</atom:title>
    </collection>
  </workspace>
</service>
```

Yes, I'm fully aware, that the entities have different names. It's not what my issue is.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25269213/458354) address what you are trying to accomplish? It will add an atom formatter to the request handlers. Unfortunately, v4 does not add it by default.

Comment: @mdisibio: Thanks. Already tried it. It does produce XML, but not in the correct format. See my updates.

Comment: Arrrg...It took me so long to figure out how to get an xml response, that I never noticed it was plain-old xml and not Atom. 
[This is the closest explanation](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/03/asp-net-odata-4) I've found that makes any sense, as of the the 6.1 libs:

_OData core libraries are capable of serializing the OData v4 Atom format but this is not officially supported since Atom specification is not at CS2 stage yet._

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from this link:
[How to disable Formatters in Web Api OData web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213737/how-to-disable-formatters-in-web-api-odata-web-service)

You can add whatever formatters you wish to use in your WebApiConfig. So for your example, I think you want to do this:

```
var odataFormatters = ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create();
odataFormatters = odataFormatters.Where(
    f => f.SupportedMediaTypes.Any(
        m => m.MediaType == "application/atom+xml" ||
            m.MediaType == "application/atomsvc+xml")).ToList();

config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.AddRange(odataFormatters);
```

Comment: With your solution I get `406Not Acceptable`